# Cant query SqlServer Resource Pool counters

Tags: sql-server, powershell, metrics

I want to collect disk IO metrics on Sql Server. For some reason I can't get the counters for `Resource Pool Stats`:

```
[db_server]: PS C:> Get-Counter -ListSet '*Resource Pool Stats*' | select -ExpandProperty pathsWIthInstances
\SQLServer:Resource Pool Stats(*)\CPU usage %
\SQLServer:Resource Pool Stats(*)\CPU usage target %
\SQLServer:Resource Pool Stats(*)\CPU control effect %
\SQLServer:Resource Pool Stats(*)\CPU effective %
\SQLServer:Resource Pool Stats(*)\CPU delayed %
\SQLServer:Resource Pool Stats(*)\CPU violated %
\SQLServer:Resource Pool Stats(*)\Compile memory target (KB)
\SQLServer:Resource Pool Stats(*)\Cache memory target (KB)
\SQLServer:Resource Pool Stats(*)\Query exec memory target (KB)
\SQLServer:Resource Pool Stats(*)\Memory grants/sec
\SQLServer:Resource Pool Stats(*)\Active memory grants count
\SQLServer:Resource Pool Stats(*)\Memory grant timeouts/sec
\SQLServer:Resource Pool Stats(*)\Active memory grant amount (KB)
\SQLServer:Resource Pool Stats(*)\Pending memory grants count
\SQLServer:Resource Pool Stats(*)\Max memory (KB)
\SQLServer:Resource Pool Stats(*)\Used memory (KB)
\SQLServer:Resource Pool Stats(*)\Target memory (KB)
\SQLServer:Resource Pool Stats(*)\Disk Read IO/sec
\SQLServer:Resource Pool Stats(*)\Disk Read IO Throttled/sec
\SQLServer:Resource Pool Stats(*)\Disk Read Bytes/sec
\SQLServer:Resource Pool Stats(*)\Avg Disk Read IO (ms)
\SQLServer:Resource Pool Stats(*)\Disk Write IO/sec
\SQLServer:Resource Pool Stats(*)\Disk Write IO Throttled/sec
\SQLServer:Resource Pool Stats(*)\Disk Write Bytes/sec
\SQLServer:Resource Pool Stats(*)\Avg Disk Write IO (ms)

[db_server]: PS C:> Get-Counter -Counter '\SQLServer:Resource Pool Stats(*)\Disk Read IO/sec'
Get-Counter : The specified instance is not present.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CounterApiError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounterComm
```

On the other hand different counter works

```
[db_server]: PS C:> Get-Counter -Counter '\SQLServer:Buffer Manager\Lazy writes/sec' -SampleInterval 5

Timestamp                 CounterSamples
---------                 --------------
18.10.2018. 12.22.01      \\db_server\sqlserver:buffer manager\lazy writes/sec :
                        0
```

What am I missing ? Essentially, I want to get this graph that is available in Sql Server Activity Monitor (image taken from the same server).

[image]

Notice, many sql server counters return 0 like the one above (but not all). Some can't return 0 like `sqlserver:memory manager\total server memory (kb)`

Comment: This works for me (tm). It's curious that you should get the `(*)` counters when expanding `pathsWithInstances` -- I only get the actual counters (marked with `(default)` and `(internal)`, respectively). But when I do `Get-Counter -Counter '\SQLServer:Resource Pool Stats(*)\Disk Read IO/sec'`, I do get back two counters. I am using PowerShell 5.1, though, maybe that makes a difference.

Comment: Using 5.1 also on Windows Server and Sql Server Enterprise 2016. I also tried with default/internal names as I know they exist on any sql server.

Comment: You appear to be remoting elsewhere, though. Is `db_server` using PowerShell 5 as well? What does `$psversiontable` give?

Comment: I tried on staging environment with the same infra and installed with the same automation! and there it works, but shows 0 all the time. Powershell version is the same on all environments: `Version          : 5.1.14393.1198`